# How to verify clipboard is empty in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to copy the display result in the clipboard. Copying is working fine. But I wanted to verify if the clipboard is empty or not. I have tried to match the div is empty, but its not helping. Can anyone help?

```js
function num_Gen() {

  document.getElementById('display100').innerHTML = document.getElementById('num1').value;

}

function CopyClip(copy_num) {
  
  var cpy = document.createRange();
  var text = document.getElementById("copy_num");
  cpy.selectNode(document.getElementById("copy_num"));
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  window.getSelection().addRange(cpy);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  if (text === "") {
    alert("Nothing copied");
  }else{
  var bubble = document.getElementById("display_num");
  bubble.innerHTML = "   value copied";

 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Value Gen</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="scr.js"></script>


  <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" required><br><br>

  <input type="button" id="display1" onclick="num_Gen()" value="View Number" />


  <button type="button" id="copy" onclick="CopyClip()">copy</button>
  <span class="bubbletext" id="display_num"></span>
  <p></p>
  <div id="copy_num">
    <span id='display100'></span><br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: - maybe you can create a hidden input which will paste the data from clipboard then you check if there's nothing alert it's empty but paste from clipboard require the user permission because browser's doesn't allow this for security reasons check [Interact with the clipboard on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

Comment: You mean you want to check if it's empty before or after **you** try to put something into it. I.e are you trying to prevent overriding anything that would be in the user's clipboard or are you trying to check if the copying worked, or even, are you trying to check preemptively if this will copy something more than an empty string to clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per i understood your question you can try this

```js
function num_Gen() {
  document.getElementById('display100').innerHTML = document.getElementById('num1').value;
}

function CopyClip(copy_num) {
  
  var cpy = document.createRange();
  var text = document.getElementById("copy_num");
//Checking for empty value before perform copy 
//getting div's text content and removed extra spaces
  if (text.textContent.trim() === "") {
    alert("Nothing copied");
    //nothing copied return 
    return;
  }
  cpy.selectNode(document.getElementById("copy_num"));
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  window.getSelection().addRange(cpy);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

  var bubble = document.getElementById("display_num");
  bubble.innerHTML = "   value copied";
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" required><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="display1" onclick="num_Gen()" value="View Number" />


  <button type="button" id="copy" onclick="CopyClip()">copy</button>
  <span class="bubbletext" id="display_num"></span>
  <p></p>
  <div id="copy_num">
    <span id='display100'></span><br>
  </div>
```